# Mongosniff Error : unknown opcode

Tags: mongodb

*** CANNOT HANDLE TYPE: 2010
10.117.241.104:27017  <<--  10.117.241.104:51907 hosts  465 bytes  id:14429c    1327772
    unknown opcode 2011

Answer (score 1):

> unknown opcode 2011

You are trying to use an older version of `mongosniff` to inspect traffic for a MongoDB server that uses a newer version of the MongoDB wire protocol.

Specifically, it looks like you are using a version of `mongosniff` older than 3.2 to inspect traffic from MongoDB 3.2 (which added the [2011 opcode for `dbCommandReply`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.2/src/mongo/util/net/message.h#L72)).

To fix this you should use a version of `mongosniff` that matches your MongoDB server deployment.